# can open command in perl execute .bat script?

Tags: perl

I've this subroutine whitch start a .bat script but I don't see which line do that.

```
sub Traitement_Proc {

   foreach my $input (@_) {

    my $cmd = Fonctions_communes::ResolvEnvDos($input);
    my ($proc, $args);
    my $chExec;
    if ($cmd =~ /^\"/) {
        ($proc, $args) = $cmd =~ /^\"(.+?)\"(.*)/;
    } else {
        ($proc, $args) = $cmd =~ /^([^\s]+)(.*)/;
    }
    $chExec = File::Spec->catfile($::G_ParamTable{$::cstExecDir}, $proc);
    $chExec = File::Spec->rel2abs($chExec, File::Spec->curdir());
    $chExec = "\"".$chExec."\"" . $args;

    Fonctions_communes::PrintError("  PROC : "._("Execution of script")." <" . $chExec . ">");

    open PROC_OUT, $chExec." 2>&1"." & if ERRORLEVEL 1 exit/b 1"." |";
    while(my $output = <PROC_OUT>) {
        chomp($output);
        Fonctions_communes::PrintError(decode($Fonctions_communes::console_encoding,$output));
    }
    close(PROC_OUT);
    if ($? == 1) {
        Fonctions_communes::PrintError(_("The script [_1] ended in failure.",basename($chExec)).".\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;
```

}

inside `$input` there is the name of bat file whitch passed in argument, there is no `$args` in my case so the `chExec` variable is `"C:\Users\anes.yahiaoui\Desktop\SPOOC_BD_TU_BD_XX_BD\tieme_RE_PCCA_BD_MAIN\RE_PCCA\BD\avantBDD\Gene_CSV\Proc\IMPORT_INV.bat"`.

when I call this function (Traitement_proc) my IMPORT_INV will start but I don't see which line do that ?

Comment: Try to use '\\' instead '\'

Comment: @AndreCarneiro I didn't got what do u mean

Comment: @AndreCarneiro there is no problem in the code it works! the problem is that I don't see in witch line it starts the .bat file. 
I think we can start a .bat script with "system" command in perl not "open" !

Comment: My mistake! I accidentally give a answer for other question. Sorry!

Comment: You can use readpipe, exec or system to call your outside function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) executing the command. Both `open(my $pipe, "shell_cmd |")` and `open(my $pipe, "-|", "shell_cmd")` execute a shell command with the other end of the pipe in `$pipe` attached to its STDOUT.

For example,

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Win32::ShellQuote qw( quote_system_string );

open(my $pipe, quote_system_string(@ARGV)." |")
   or die $!;

while (<$pipe>) {
   chomp;
   say("[$_]");
}

if (!close($pipe)) {
   die("Error waiting for child to exit: $!\n")      if $!;
   die("Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
   die("Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n")  if $? >> 8;
}

say("Child completed successfully.");
```

```
>a.pl perl -le"print for 1..5"
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
Child completed successfully.
```